# imwrite python not saving image [Mac]

Tags: macos, python-3.x, opencv3.0

I am trying to save a frame from a video playback. The code runs without any errors, however, i could not find my saved image in my folder. Below is the script that i have written. I am using python version 3.5 and OpenCV3 on a mac. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Applications/OpenCV3/build/lib/python3')

import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

i = 0
Mx = cv2.VideoCapture('LB.mp4')
if Mx.isOpened()== True:
    print('',Mx.isOpened())
else:
    print('',Mx.isOpened())

while(Mx.isOpened()):
    print('i = ', i)
    ret, frame = Mx.read()
    cv2.imshow('Original',frame)
    cv2.waitKey(50)
    i += 1
    if i == 10:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imwrite = ('Missile.bmp', gray)
        print('Imaged saved at i = ', i)
        break

print('End of While Loop')
Mx.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Where are you running the script from? I'd check there.

Comment: I am running my script from IDLE